# How to call the CreateUser method from a webreference

Tags: c#, web-reference, createuser

I've ran out of things to try, so I hope someone can help me with this.

I'm creating a "Register" page. When a user clicks the "Register" button, their information (email, username, password) needs to be stored into an Access database.

I've created a web reference ( http://localhost:36938/usconWebServices/membershipService.asmx ) and trying to call the "CreateUser" function in the register.aspx.cs, but can't seem to get it right.

Here's what I have for register.aspx.cs:

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wrefMembership.membershipService ws = new wrefMembership.membershipService();

    if (ws.CreateUser(txtEmailReg.Text, txtUsernameReg, txtPasswordReg))
    {

        try
        {
            Response.Redirect("mainContent.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Response.Write("<b>Something really bad happened... Please try again.</b>");
        }
        finally
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/membersOnly/mainContent.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

The 3rd line starting with "if..." is giving me an error: "No over for method 'CreateUser' takes 3 arguements." I've tried taking out the parameters as well as the entire line, but still didn't work.

And here's what I have for membershipService.cs:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Create a new user, pass on a user object, returns a result string with information about processing result")]
public string CreateUser(user newUser, string emailAddress, string username, string userPassword)
{
    string query = "";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataRow dr;
    int count;
    string result = "";

    try
    {
        //define query
        query = "SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE emailAddress='" + newUser.emailAddress + "'";
        ds = DataAccessService.RunSimpleQuery(query);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 0)
        {
            dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            dr["emailAddress"] = newUser.emailAddress;
            dr["username"] = newUser.username;
            dr["userPassword"] = userPassword;
            dr["registerDate"] = DateTime.Now;
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
            result = DataAccessService.RunInsertCommand(query, ds);

            try
            {
                ds = DataAccessService.RunSimpleQuery(query);
                count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; //last row is the new row!
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[count - 1];
                    result = "[000] OK: userID=" + dr["userID"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    result = "[004] ERROR: User ID not found"; //user ID not found
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = "ERROR: Could not update database: " + ex.Message + " *** ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = "[003] ERROR: This e-mail account has already been registered with us."; //e-mail account already exists
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = "[002] ERROR: " + query + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace; //error
    }

    return result;
}
```

Any help or advice on this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CreateUser() function expects four parameters (user newUser, string emailAddress, string username, string userPassword). But when you are calling that method, you are passing only three parameters.

Change

```
if (ws.CreateUser(txtEmailReg.Text, txtUsernameReg, txtPasswordReg))
```

to pass all the four parameters.

```
user newUser=new Users();
if (ws.CreateUser(newUser,txtEmailReg.Text, txtUsernameReg.Text, txtPasswordReg.Text))
```

Obviously you are missing the first parameter, the object of user class.

Or change your function definition

```
public string CreateUser(user newUser, string emailAddress, string username, string userPassword)
```

to

```
public string CreateUser(string emailAddress, string username, string userPassword)
```

which accepts only three parameters

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, giftcv. I added the "user" class to create 4 parameters and it gave me a red line underneath the word. So I hover over it and it suggested that I add "using wrefMembership;" which I did. Then the entire line became an error. When I hover over the word "user" again, it says: "Error: 'wrefMembership.user' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'." How do I do that? (sorry, I'm really new to this...) Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, giftcv! It still gave me an error, so I decided to try it inside the try-catch instead:  user newUser = new user();

        try
        {
            ws.CreateUser(newUser, txtEmailReg.Text, txtUsernameReg.Text, txtPasswordReg.Text);

Comment: haha there are no more errors in that part. The new user's info is stored in the database after also I fixed something else. Thanks again for your help!